# A simple question on isometry

Tags: linear-algebra

In Lemma 2.4 here http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01215346#page-2
why is $\sigma$ an isometry and why is $\sigma(S)^\perp=\sigma(S^\perp)$?

"Lemma 2.4. Let $S$ be a linear subspace of the space of real-valued functions on
$\{1,-1\}^n$, and let $f$ be a function from $\{1,-1\}^n$ ~ to $\{1,-1\}$. Then there exists some $p\in S$ which strongly represents $f$ if and only if there does not exist any nonzero $q\in S^\perp$ such which weakly represents $f$.

Proof. Let $\sigma$ be the linear transformation which maps $g$ to $fg$. Then $\sigma(f)$ is the constant $1$ and, since $\sigma$ is easily seen to be an isometry, $\sigma(S)^\perp=\sigma(S^\perp)$. Thus we
may assume without loss of generality that $f$ is $1$.

Regard $S$ as the set of solutions $p$ to $Ap = 0$ for some appropriate matrix $A$;
then $S^\perp$ is the row space of $A$ consisting of all vectors of the form $q=yA$. We may thus recast the original statement as: there exists $p$ such that $Ap = 0$ and $p > 0$ if and only if there does not exist $q = yA$ such that $q\neq0$ and $q\geq0$".

Comment: How do I copy and paste the lemma?

Comment: Typed in Lemma here fully .

Answer (score 1):

Since the vector space in question is finite-dimensional, we're probably speaking about the usual euclidean norm: For $g : \{-1,1\}^n\to \mathbb R$ we have
$$|g|=\sqrt{\sum_{i\in\{-1,1\}^n} g(i)^2}$$

However, then when $f:\{-1,1\}^n\to\{-1,1\}$ we have
$$|\sigma(g)|=|fg|=\sqrt{\sum_{i\in\{-1,1\}^n} (gf)(i)^2}
=\sqrt{\sum_{i\in\{-1,1\}^n} g(i)^2 f(i)^2}
=\sqrt{\sum_{i\in\{-1,1\}^n} g(i)^2}
=|g| $$
because $f(i)^2=1$ always, so $\sigma$ preserves the norm.

That $\sigma$ commutes with taking orthogonal complement is then just a standard facts about norm-preserving (that is, orthogonal) linear transformations of a finite-dimensional vector space.